# Sphinxsearch min_infix_len = 1 is disabled by force on 2.2.x?

Tags: sphinx

I had a previous version of SphinxSearch that worked like charm. Was fast and the results were accurate for me. After upgrading to 2.2.10 many changes occurred on that release that made the search results much worse.

Now if I am searching for example "Lenovo y" from existing "lenovo y5070" I get no results although I have in my config:

> ```
> min_word_len = 1
> min_infix_len = 1
> ```

searching for "Lenovo y5" does work fine so to me it seems that the infix is forced to use "2" instead of 1. This is very bad for my search results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [expand_keywords = 1](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-expand-keywords.html) with [index_exact_words](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-index-exact-words.html) = 1